# Need consistent javac and java

Tags: java, windows, revision

Just installed java 1.7 update 51 on a Windows 7 machine.  AFAICT, when I compile a source, the system automatically uses the new java.  But I try to run it, the system automatically tried to run it with an old java 1.6, and the newly compiled code won't run.  How do I convince the machine to use only the 1.7 distribution?

Comment: fix your paths ahd classpaths

Comment: Uninstall the 1.6 runtime.

Comment: Change your `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables to point to the 1.7 installation if you want to keep the 1.6.

Comment: Or set the target to 1.6 while compiling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492948/javac-source-and-target-options

Comment: I confirmed that there's no reason to keep the 1.6 (and I understand old java versions present security issues anyway) so I just uninstalled the 11.6 and now everything is fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have java.exe in your System32 folder?
I suspect this might be your problem.
See this question I recently asked.

[Java Windows7 System32 folder java.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412853/java-windows7-system32-folder-java-exe)

I suggest you remove both JDKs, then you install them both without the
option to install a public JRE (be careful about this at installation time).

Also, make sure you understand/control what is in your PATH variable.

I also have both 6 and 7 on my machine, and
since I got rid of the public JREs I am fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the JDK (java development kit with javac compiler), and the JRE (java runtime environment). Simply doing an additional JRE 7 installation will do. (This might have been asked during the installation of the JDK.)

Comment: As I am generally running Linux, consider @peterpetrov first.